# How do I check if there's a nil set or not in an array?

Tags: ruby, arrays, null

If I set some `nil` values to an array, I don't seem to be able to check for them. I have tried `any?` and `empty?`.

```
array = [nil, nil, nil]
#=> [nil, nil, nil]

array[1].any?
#=> "NoMethodError: undefined method `any?' for nil:NilClass"
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`any?` iterates over a container, like an array, and looks at each element passed to it to see if it passes a test. If one does, the loop stops and `true` is returned:

```
ary = [nil, 1]

ary.any?{ |e| e.nil? } # => true
```

[The documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F) explains this well:

> Passes each element of the collection to the given block. The method returns true if the block ever returns a value other than false or nil. If the block is not given, Ruby adds an implicit block of { |obj| obj } that will cause any? to return true if at least one of the collection members is not false or nil.

```
%w[ant bear cat].any? { |word| word.length >= 3 } #=> true
%w[ant bear cat].any? { |word| word.length >= 4 } #=> true
[nil, true, 99].any?                              #=> true
```

`any?` is one of a number of tests that can be applied to an array to determine if there are [`none?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-none-3F), `any?`, [`one?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-one-3F), or [`all?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-all-3F).

```
ary.one?{ |e| e == 1 } # => true
ary.none?{ |e| e == 2 } # => true
ary.all? { |e| e.nil? } # => false
```

Your code fails because you're trying to use a non-existing `any?` method for a nil value, hence the error you got: "NoMethodError: undefined method `any?' for nil:NilClass"

```
ary[0] # => nil
ary.first # => nil
ary.first.respond_to?(:'any?') # => false
```

You have to pay attention to what you're doing. `ary[0]` or `array.first` returns the element at that array index, not an array.

[`empty?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-empty-3F) only checks to see if the container has elements in it. In other words, does it have a size > 0?

```
ary.empty? # => false
ary.size == 0 # => false
ary.size > 0 # => true
[].empty? # => true
[].size == 0 # => true
[].size > 0 # => false
```

Comment: Thanks! `args.any?(&:nil?)` look better for me.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to check if the array includes nil:

```
[nil, 1, 2].include?(nil) #=> true
```

Comment: Sometimes the best approach is the simplest approach, as EVERYONE will get the intent immediately when they look at the code.  Particularly if it's me coming back to it.  I don't want another "Why does that work again?" moment.  Have enough already.  This should be marked as the best answer.

Answer (score 7):

`any?`'s default bahavior is to check for ant truthy value in the array.

```
# check if there are any truthy values in the array
[nil, nil, nil].any? #=> false
[nil, true, nil].any? #=> true

# check if all values are truthy
[true,Duck.new,2,'yes'].all? #=> true
[nil, false].all? #=> false

# check if none values are truthy
[nil,false,nil].none? #=> true
[Math::PI,nil,false].none? #=> false
```

All this methods accepts an optional block to customize the value beingchecked, which comes very handy in your specific use case:

```
[false, false, false].any?(&:nil?) => false
[false, false, nil].any?(&:nil?) => true
```

Comment: Numbers is only concerned with `nil`, not `nil` or `false`.

Answer (score 2):

```
array = [nil, nil, nil]
#=> [nil, nil, nil]
array[1].nil?
#=> true
```

Answer (score 2):

You can turn nil values into booleans this way to check for them

```
array = [nil, nil, nil]
#=> [nil, nil, nil]
!array[1]
#=> true
!!array[1]
#=>false
```

However, using any? checks for the existence of something. You can use

```
array.any? {|item| !item }
#=> true
```

To check if there are any values that evaluate to `false` as a `nil` value does. Be careful if you might have a `false` value in your array though because it will also be evaluated as `true` using this this method.

Or you could just use:

```
array.any? { |item| item.nil? }
```

As other posters have suggested

Your problem is that you are calling the `any?` method on nil and not on an array.

Comment: Numbers is only concerned with `nil`, not `nil` or `false`.

Comment: You're right, thats why I added the bit about nil as well :)